# Best way to implement a dirty flag in EF

Tags: frameworks, entity

You can easily use the `PropertyChanges` events to set the flag. But how do you easily reset it after a save to the `ObjectContext`?

Answer (score 1):

what about the *ObjectContext.SavingChanges* event? See also http://www.thedatafarm.com/blog/2008/07/13/OverridingObjectContextSaveChanges.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The above method calls for using the SavingChanges event which is called before the changes are persisted.  If there is an error during the save, you have already cleared your dirty flag.  I would think there would be a SavedChanges event exposed as well.